# Exception handling before deleting dynamic memory in a function

Tags: c++

I allocated dynamic memory and i am clearing the memory at the end of my function using delete operator. i have an exception handling before delete. How can i avoid memory leak in this situation.

Comment: Have you tried with a scoped pointer?

Comment: You use RAII. Use for example `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` or roll out your own guard class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::unique_ptr` or similar to hold your heap-allocated memory. Then it would be deallocated automatically when that smart pointer goes out of scope, whether or not an exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this is creating a class that contains your allocated memory and deletes it in the constructor.

This is what `std::vector` does, so when it goes out of scope, the compiler ensures that the memory is deleted (even if it goes out of scope because of a destructor).

For pointers to single values, that's what smart pointers are for. `std::auto_ptr` (now deprecated) and `std::unique_ptr` (new in C++ 2011) do that for you.